# Is there a way to rollback python packages' updates in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pickle, opencv

I am working on a project and it was working fine until I decided to update all the packages in my virtual environment of Pycharm. Now it's giving me error on the function that was working fine before. I'm getting

`'SVC' object has no attribute '_probA'`

on this line of code

`pickle.loads(open(rec, "rb").read()).predict_proba(vec)[0]`

Is there a way to rollback packages updates or what is the new attribute which will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove the package and reinstall? The installation screen gives you the option to 'Specify Version'.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ben for the correct answer. Although I didn't knew which package was causing that error as I had upgraded all but I guessed it was scikit-learn and I did installed its previous version and Voila, it worked. But I installed an older version of package than needed but thanks to Pycharm, it told me exact version of package "pickle" was created in so I was able to install the correct one. Thanks or I would have been stuck at it for some time.

Comment: @Jerry555555 Glad I could help! (I am always surprised how much Pycharm helps out with - I am way more efficient because of it)